# WebKit CSS 3d transforms not working in Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, css, webkit, osx-snow-leopard

I've compiled an application that uses WebKit on Leopard (10.5).

The application is 32 bit.
I've bundled 32 bit versions of WebKit/WebCore etc with the app.

If I run it on Snow Leopard (10.6) none of the CSS 3d transforms work. 3D transforms work in SL's Safari.

I have a feeling that my app isn't able to link with some of the 3D graphics frameworks in Snow Leopard. Are any of the graphic frameworks 64 bit only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. My goal was saving an image of a WebKit/WebView, but anything with -webkit-transform rendered blank.

This is the code I was using that did not work correctly:

```
-(NSBitmapImageRep *)getBitmap {
    return [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect: [[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] bounds]];
}
```

This code seems to fix the problem, indeed displaying objects with -webkit-transform:

```
-(NSBitmapImageRep *)getBitmap {
    NSBitmapImageRep *image = [webView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[webView bounds]];
    [webView cacheDisplayInRect:[webView bounds] toBitmapImageRep:image];
    return image;
}
```